# Is there an equivalent of Proton Packs for Hunter: The Vigil?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, weapons, hunter-the-vigil

I'm trying to develop a character loosely based off of Egon Spengler for a new H:tV game I'm planning on taking part in an I was curious if I could stat up a proton pack from the movies?

The closest I've found is Etheric Rounds (HtV pg. 150) (Etheric trackers and goggles (HTV pg.151) I've spotted, and take the place of the PKE Meter and Ecto-Goggles). But they aren't an exact match.

My only other thought is using a flamethrower as a base weapon, but this is still far off what I'm imagining.

Is there something closer to a Proton Pack that exists in a splat book for nWoD that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Make it a Tactic.**

Thinking outside the box for a moment, here's [what the proton pack actually does](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_pack#cite_note-Ghostbusters-3):

> The beam allows a ghostbuster to contain and hold "negatively charged ectoplasmic entities". This containment ability allows the wielder to position a ghost above a trap for capture.

It doesn't trap the ghost; it doesn't hurt the ghost; it makes the ghost paralyzed and able to be moved. In that regard, it's analogous to Staking a vampire, which is a Tactic from **Hunter: the Vigil** on page 228. What I'd recommend is reskinning that to use, say, Dexterity + Science rather than Strength + Weaponry, using the proton pack as a kind of unique equipment for the tactic. "Crossing the Streams," naturally, is a Dramatic Failure in most circumstances.

Comment: Nice suggestion~

Comment: This is good, though I will need to teach this to my group... interesting point!